# i'm trying to build android ionic 1 app for testing but i don't get anything

Tags: angular2-template

'i have installed android studio and installed all sdk tools and jdk 1.8 but still app is not building'

'(node:4216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This                                                                                                                 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch                                                                                                                 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection                                                                                                                 id: 1)
(node:4216) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre                                                                                                                cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the                                                                                                                 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

**ionic version 3.20.0**

> npm install -g ionic@3.20.0

**NodeJS Version 8.11.3**

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.11.3/

**Download JDK Version 1.8.0_171**

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?printOnly=1

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: its not working still same issue. is there any other solution?

Comment: You can try once using
Platform remove and platform add.